# Make a draggable element whitout setting position to absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, draggable

I have some element that I want to drag on a canvas to return their coordinates thereafter.
So elements should appear next to each other than I will be able to drag them.
The problem I am facing is the elements appear on each other not separated by space :

I am using the function `dragElement(element)` from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp to make my elements draggable.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv,
#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader,
#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="markers" class="row">
    <div id="mydiv" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv2" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader2">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the CSS position property from absolute to relative, It make elements set next to each other but I can't drag them anymore.

On the code I posted I have only two elements but actually, more new elements  will be created dynamically with a JS code.

Here is my JS code :

```
//this list will be uploaded by the user      
var d = ["module1", "module2",.......,"module22"];

for(i in d){
  append_module_name_to_drag_div(d[i]);
  dragElement(document.getElementById(d[i]));  
}

function append_module_name_to_drag_div(module_name){
  var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
  mydiv.id=module_name;
  mydiv.className ='col-sm-10';

  var mydivmarker= document.createElement("div");
  mydivmarker.id=module_name+"header";
  mydivmarker.className ='mydivheader';
  
  var marker_image = new Image();
  marker_image.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png";
  marker_image.height = 45;
  marker_image.width = 35;
  
  mydivmarker.append(marker_image);
  mydiv.innerHTML=module_name;
  mydiv.append(mydivmarker);
  document.getElementById("markers").appendChild(mydiv);
}
```

Comment: You can try with position `relative` and move it with  `transform: translate (tx, ty)` or `transform: matrix()` But you need js for that way

Comment: Yes I am using JS, but I didn't understand how to add `transform: translate (tx, ty)`? Could you explain more please?

Comment: use margin instead of `top/left`

Comment: @ZohirSalak could please explain where to add margin?

Comment: The code you from W3schools is using position absolute and updating the properties `top` and `left`, You want the dragged element to affect the flow of the document, so remove `position:absolute`  from the css and change the code to update the margins

Comment: when I remove `position: absolute` I cant drag anymore the elements, I am so sorry I didn't get your point about updating marigins

Answer (score 0):

## Original w3schools example

You can use `position: absolute` like mentioned on the linked w3schools example, but without defining `top`, `left` etc. for the absolutely positioned elements they all have the same default: `top: 0` and `left: 0`. Therefor they all appear at the same location, which leads to the stacking on top of each other.

You can prevent the stacking if you define a different value for `top`, `left` etc. for each absolutely positioned element. For example:

```
#mydiv2 {
  top: 170px;
}
```

This is a solution for your originally posted question with two hardcoded draggable elements, but it doesn't fit well for dynamically added content.

**Working example:**

For simplicity i omitted the first `if ... else` block in the function `dragElement()` and attached the event listener directly to the whole element:

```
elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
```

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv, 
#mydiv2 {
  position :absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydiv2 {
  top: 170px;
}

#mydivheader, 
#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div id="mydiv" class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mydiv2" class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="mydivheader2">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

## Using `transform: translate()`

### **Basic implementation**

For dynamically added content (or any other reason for not using `top`, `left` etc.) it would be better to use `transform: translate()` and omit `position: absolute`, so that the elements stay where they are and can't get stacked.

To bring this to work you simply have to subtract the original calculation from the old `translate`-values, which you overwrite with the values of that subtraction (to save them for the next function call):

```js
pos1 = pos1 - (pos3 - e.clientX);
pos2 = pos2 - (pos4 - e.clientY);
```

Last you have to change the two lines where the styling occurs from `top` and `left` to one line with `translate`:

```js
elmnt.style.transform = 'translate(' + (pos1) + "px, " + (pos2) + "px)";
```

**Working example:**

I exchanged the outdated `var` with `let` because the vars will change.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  let pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos1 - (pos3 - e.clientX);
    pos2 = pos2 - (pos4 - e.clientY);
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.transform = 'translate(' + (pos1) + "px, " + (pos2) + "px)";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv,
#mydiv2 {
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader,
#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="mydiv" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv2" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader2">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **Speaking vars**

The names of the vars in the w3schools example `pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4` aren't very intuitive. Therefor they should be renamed to easyly understand what they are for: `translate = { x: 0, y: 0 }` and `client = { x: 0, y: 0 }`.

**Working example:**

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  let translate = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let client = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    client.x = e.clientX;
    client.y = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    translate.x = translate.x - (client.x - e.clientX);
    translate.y = translate.y - (client.y - e.clientY);
    client.x = e.clientX;
    client.y = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.transform = 'translate(' + (translate.x) + "px, " + (translate.y) + "px)";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv,
#mydiv2 {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#mydivheader,
#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="mydiv" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv2" class="col-sm-10">
      <div id="mydivheader2">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **Final implementation**

To demonstrate the code with your later added function for dynamically adding draggable elements, here the final implementation. I exchanged the outdated `var` with `const` because the vars won't change.

**Working example:**

```js
const d = ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5"];

for(i in d) {
  append_module_name_to_drag_div(d[i]);
  dragElement(document.getElementById(d[i]));  
}
  
function append_module_name_to_drag_div(module_name) {
  const mydiv = document.createElement("div");
  mydiv.id = module_name;
  mydiv.className = 'module col-sm-10';

  const mydivmarker = document.createElement("div");
  mydivmarker.id = module_name+"header";
  mydivmarker.className = 'mydivheader';
  
  const marker_image = new Image();
  marker_image.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png";
  marker_image.height = 45;
  marker_image.width = 35;
  
  mydivmarker.append(marker_image);
  mydiv.innerHTML = module_name;
  mydiv.append(mydivmarker);
  document.getElementById("markers").appendChild(mydiv);
}

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  let translate = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let client = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    client.x = e.clientX;
    client.y = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    translate.x = translate.x - (client.x - e.clientX);
    translate.y = translate.y - (client.y - e.clientY);
    client.x = e.clientX;
    client.y = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.transform = 'translate(' + (translate.x) + "px, " + (translate.y) + "px)";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.module {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="markers" class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how I can position many new elements that will be created dynamically with a JS code,

Comment: This could be answered if you would show the code that creates the elements dynamically...

Comment: I ve already edit the question and I added the JS code

Comment: @ab.fe I updated my answer. Please give a feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved this two days ago fixing `left` and `top` for every element each time on the loop. Is it what you did also, I hope this will help someone in the future, I forgot to post my solution too, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The elements appear on top of each other because your `#mydiv` has `position: absolute` declared, which takes it out of the document flow. Elements out of flow will be placed on top of the flowing elements, as specified by CSS.

[Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14135825) suggested to use the CSS-function [`translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()) for moving, instead of `position: absolute` with `top` etc. This would leave the elements in the flow, meaning they will still be considered.

As `translate()` will take effect after re-flow (re-validating the flow of the document), it won't mess with your layout even when the draggable elements are moved.

If you're only interested in the result, skip ahead. But here's some more information.

<sub>*W3Schools was (is?) notorious for being somewhat outdated or sometimes even featuring bad advice, so I advise to do some research on top of reading their articles.*</sub>

Now, [W3Schools' `dragElement()`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)-function works great for backwards-compatibility, because it is written for browsers of 2011 and earlier. Nowadays most (if not all) browsers implement HTML5, CSS3 and (at least) ES6 (the JavaScript specification), as well as certain browser standards.

This means, the following (and more!) will be supported:

- Use of `const`/`let`.
  Difference between them and `var`: They declare block-scope variables, and aren't hoisted. However, using them will make debugging easier, and will convey this message:

  - `const` implies that the reference won't ever change.
  - `let` implies that the reference *may* be changed.
- Use of [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) for searching descendants of an element. (Similar to [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).)
- Use of [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)/[`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).
  This solves the problem of only ever being able to assign
  one event-listener to an element when using `onevent`-listeners.
- Use of [(lambda) arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Can often be used as an
  alternative to functions, but they are **not hoisted**.
- More semantic HTML-tags! This is very important as their use is (IMO) the main focus-point of [web-accessibility](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility).

Some off-topic points:

- I highly suggest to learn writing your own CSS first before using a CSS-library or similar.
- I also highly suggest learning (or at least reading *once*) about all the HTML-tags. This not only helps your understanding of the language, it also allows you to create accessible pages, which is inherently necessary to know about for SEO.
- I'd also like to mention the effort of Google, Microsoft, and others for working on a [standard of marking up](https://schema.org/) all sorts of stuff. This might also be relevant for SEO, but is a huge chunk of reading-material.

## Refactorization

First off, I'll remove any pre-existing comments, so that the new comments can explain the changes.

Some people prefer `'` (single-quote) over `"` (double-quote) for strings, as it is more likely that you want to use `"` than `'` in a string. Using one allows the other to be used unescaped.
I prefer `'` in JS, so don't be confused over why my changes use them.

I replaced all instances of `var` with either `const` or `let`, depending on what seemed more appropriate.

The code will now use `addEventListener()`/`removeEventListener()` instead of `onevent`-listener.

Most important changes:

- In HTML:

  - Draggable elements now use `draggable`-class
  - Use of correct tags:

    - For headers, use `<header>`
    - If draggable element contains `<header>`, make it a `<section>`
- In CSS:

  - Add rule for `draggable`-class
  - Add [enabling CSS rule(s)](https://www.silvestar.codes/articles/you-want-a-single-enabling-selector-not-the-one-that-disables-the-rule-of-the-previous-one/) for when `draggable` is also a `<section>`
- In JS:

  - Use of `xPos`,`yPos` instead of `pos0`, `pos1`, `pos2`, `pos3`
  - Update position-values using [`MouseEvent.movementX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) (and `.movementY`)
  - Update on-screen position using [`Element.styles.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) with `translate()`

```js
// Make all `.draggable` draggable
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'))
  dragElement(el);

// May be changed? Hence `let`
let d = ["module1", "module2", "module22"];

// Changed loop to for...of, because we only want to iterate over the array-elements
for (const el of d) {
  append_module_name_to_drag_div(el);
  dragElement(document.getElementById(el));  
}

function append_module_name_to_drag_div(module_name){
  const mydiv = document.createElement("div");

  mydiv.id = module_name;
  mydiv.className = 'col-sm-10 draggable'; // Added '.draggable'

  const mydivmarker = document.createElement("div");
  const marker_image = new Image();
  marker_image.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png";
  marker_image.height = 45;
  marker_image.width = 35;
  mydivmarker.append(marker_image);
  
  // Generally bad to use .innerHTML with user-generated content.
  // Prefer .innerText or .textContent.
  // Read more on:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations
  mydiv.innerText = module_name;
  
  mydiv.append(mydivmarker);
  
  // Changed to .append(), try to stay consistent!
  // I suggest using .append() over .appendChild(), as the former allows
  // an arbitrary amount of arguments.
  document.getElementById("markers").append(mydiv);
}

// Originally from: "How to create a draggable HTML element" - W3Schools
// ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp )
function dragElement(el) {
  // We'll only need x- and y-positions; may/will change, hence `let`
  let xPos = 0;
  let yPos = 0;
  if (el.querySelector('header')) // Use Element.querySelector() to avoid using unnecessary IDs
    el.querySelector('header').addEventListener('mousedown', dragMouseDown);
  else
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', dragMouseDown);
  
  function dragMouseDown(event) {
    // The event-object will always be passed; no need to refer to window.event
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // No need to save initial mouse-position
    
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', closeDragElement);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
  }
  function elementDrag(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // New positions calculated using MouseEvent.(movementX|movementY)
    xPos += event.movementX;
    yPos += event.movementY;
    
    // Set position as translate() of .style.transform
    el.style.transform = `translate(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px)`;
  }
  function closeDragElement() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', closeDragElement);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Add enabling CSS for .draggable */
/* Enabling CSS:
 * Only declare properties when rules apply.
 */
/* Disabling CSS:
 * Declare all "default" properties.
 * Reset all then-unwanted properties.
 * May overwrite other rule's declarations in the process.
 */
/* Related: https://www.silvestar.codes/articles/you-want-a-single-enabling-selector-not-the-one-that-disables-the-rule-of-the-previous-one/ */

.draggable {width: fit-content} /* Default */
.draggable:not(section) {cursor: move} /* Enabling CSS */
section.draggable {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
section.draggable>header {
  padding: .625rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="markers" class="row">
  <!--Change draggable sections to <section> where appropriate-->
  <section id="mydiv" class="col-sm-10 draggable"> <!--Add class "draggable" for styling-->
    <header>Click here to move</header> <!--May have a header; dragElement() now searches for such-->
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="mydiv2" class="col-sm-10 draggable">
    <header>Click here to move</header>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't understand what do you mean exactly? Should I change the whole code structure? Is there any way to just set the position of elements and prevent them from overleaping?

Comment: @Abdoo.fe To be honest, I only implemented a way of using the CSS-function `translate()` without considering the code you already had. Thus, my answer (so far!) is only an example of how such an implementation could look like, but I'll update it soon. Preventing the elements from overlapping can be done by checking if they overlap, and if so, re-calculating the positions (e.g. by clamping them to not be inside another element's bounding-box).

Comment: If you can just have a look at my code and see if I am missing something that leads to overlapping elements, thanks.

Comment: @Abdoo.fe Well, currently you take `#mydiv` out of the flow by using `position: absolute`. That's why it will be ontop of other elements, as the flowing content is layed out first, and the out-of-flow content later ontop. Greg suggested to leave the element in the flow (by not using `position: absolute`), and allow dragging by using `transform: translate(tx, ty)`.

Comment: @Abdoo.fe My answer should now provide (at least) the necessary information regarding your problem, as well as some further reading material and links. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to set `top` and `left` for every element each time, and this will let every element in a separate position without breaking the graggable part :

```
const d = ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5"];



 for(i in d){
      append_module_name_to_drag_div(d[i],top,left);
      dragElement(document.getElementById(d[i]));  

      if(left<220){left=left+39;}
      //you can set here height and width: in my case 300 was the width of the container, 35 was the width of markers
      else{
        left=5;
        top=top+70;//70 height of marker
      }
    }
```

I modified this function to have two more parametrs to specify the top and left:

```
function append_module_name_to_drag_div(module_name,top,left){
  var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
  
  mydiv.id=module_name;
  mydiv.className ='col-sm-10';// 'col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-sm-6';//'mydiv';

  var mydivmarker= document.createElement("div");
  mydivmarker.id=module_name+"header";
  mydivmarker.className ='mydivheader';// 'col-sm-4';//'mydivheader';
  var marker_image = new Image();
  marker_image.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png";
  marker_image.height = 45;
  marker_image.width = 35;
  mydivmarker.append(marker_image);

  // var p = document.createElement("p");
  mydiv.innerHTML=module_name;
  // mydiv.append(p);
  mydiv.append(mydivmarker);

  ///***
  // mydiv.style.cssFloat = "left";
  mydiv.style.left = left.toString()+"px";
  mydiv.style.top = top.toString()+"px";
///**** */

  document.getElementById("markers").appendChild(mydiv);
  var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
  document.getElementById("markers").appendChild(linebreak);
  
  
}
```

The function from W3Schools except the two line where(//set the element's new position:)

```
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```